Django check if a user is connected to wi-fi
I would like to check if a user is connected to wi-fi. If the user is connected to WiFi than they would be able to upload a video. If the user is not connected to WiFi than they would not be able to upload a video. I am not checking for internet instead I am checking for WiFi since cellular data counts as internet. The reason I don’t want Cellular data is because it is weak for video uploads and creates load problems which I would like to block in all.

You can use the NetworkInformation object in the browser, although that can be spoofed...

@willeM_VanOnsem looking at the support that solution seems very unsupported. Is there any other solution you may know?

I would hope not, since I would never want to use a browser that is so unconcerned about privacy.
